# JPA throws - "ERROR: user lacks privilege or object not found: BOOK"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hsqldb

In my project I'm using HSQLDB as a Database. Constructed the DB and added two entries. Now I am trying to get those entries with JPA. Unfortunately, get following exception

> ERROR: user lacks privilege or object not found: BOOK
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:492)
>       at com.top.shelf.lib.entityManagers.BookManager.main(BookManager.java:48)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1928)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1897)
>       at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1875)

here is my `persistance.xml` file.

```
    <class>com.top.shelf.lib.entityManager.Book</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:MyDB" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And my Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "AUTHOR")
    private String author;

    @Column(name = "BRIEF_DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "ISBN")
    private String isbn;

    @Column(name = "LOCATION")
    private String location;

    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private String user_id;

    public Book(String title, String author, String description, String isbn,
            String location) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.description = description;
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public String getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

}
```

Comment: add persistence.xml       <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
      <persistence-unit name="manager" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
       <class>com.top.shelf.lib.entityManager.Book</class>

        <properties>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:MyDB"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
          <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
          <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
      </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

Comment: Now I don't get any exception but the result is set is empty

Comment: Is the database the record?

Comment: Yes, there are two entries in the table. But shows empty result.
`Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT b FROM Book b WHERE b.title = :title");`
`System.out.println(q.getResultList().size());`

Comment: Even for this query - `Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT b FROM Book b");` the result is 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100754/discussion-between-jackk-and-rauf-agayev).